# iOS: PayTm-Something went wrong. It may be due to any of these reasons

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-gateway, checksum, paytm

i am trying to integrate `payTm` `payment` `gateway`(`Production`) in my app.
i generate all the required `credentials` for it but when i press pay button from app it get redirected to payTm page and `OOPS` Something went wrong screen... appears

[image]

Comment: You can drop an email at : payments.onboarding@paytm.com

Comment: bhai kuchh solution mila??