# Error linker command failed with exit code 1 (while Paytm payment integration)

Tags: ios, objective-c, paytm

I have this errors while compiling my code after writing code for **Paytm payment Integration** in my app. Here I attach a Screen Shot for the error:

[image: Error]

1. I have tried restarting Xcode/ Clean Build.
2. Added **System configuration framework** to my project as per [this step-0](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit)
3. Followed all the steps as per[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35498658/7755028)

Has anyone faced this type of issue ever?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after two days of scratching my head and trying almost all the solutions, I found a simple problem while adding **Paytm Library.**

I would like you to be aware while integrating Paytm.

Here are the correct steps to follow:

1. Add Paytm Libraries instead of using **pod 'Paytm-Payments'**

   - Here is the link [to download the Github repo](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit) and get the Library
2. Don't forget to add **Paytm Sdk** just under your main project. (Not under Libraries folder)
3. Set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** in **Build Settings.**
4. Now Clean your project and Build again.

That's it. You're all set.

For more detail, go through this [documentation](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit).

Thanks :)